# webpack load html along with its linked css to inline conversion

Tags: javascript, frontend, webpack

How we can make webpack *html-loader* to convert linked css scripts to be inline  css so overall html will be packed instead of containing remote components.

```
var viewHTML=require('html!./../../themes/frontend/default/widget.html');
```

so basically instead of making use of css-loader in js, i want that html-loader or someone else to automatically process things like link[rel="stylesheet"] and replace with  tags.